# H.264 Pro Recorder Files not closed properly

Tags: video, encoding, h.264

I have several files that were recorded using a [**BlackMagic Design H.264 Pro Recorder**](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/h264prorecorder).  It would appear that somewhere in the process, the recorder did not close out the file properly when the recording was stopped at the end of the session.  As a result, I have several large files that might contain some form of recording. Unfortunately, I cannot open them in any software that I have tried.

Does anyone have any solution for software that may open these so that we can provide them to our client, or on something that may repair them so that they are usable?